# Why are my columns displayed in the wrong order when using order class on a col in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, col

In the code below, why are the last 3 Cards in the ordering getting displayed first on the web page? With the "order-*" terms removed they are in the correct order. See resulting picture at bottom. This seems to happen whenever I use more than 5 elements in the row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container w-100">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-1 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">CARD 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-2 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">CARD 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">CARD 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">CARD 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-5 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">CARD 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">CARD 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-7 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">CARD 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 order-lg-8 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">CARD 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It only goes up to 5.

> Includes support for 1 through 5 across all six grid tiers.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes